# Session doesn't start in a specific page

Tags: php, session, header

Edit: I fixed it, the problem was the spaces before `<?php`.
Thanks for the comments.

Sessions are working on all pages except index.php

The error:
session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home/site/public_html/connection.php on line 13

connection.php:

```
<?php

try {
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb','testuser','123456');
$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); }
catch(PDOExpception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); }

ob_start(); session_start(); # (line 13)

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php'; include 'seo.php';
$connect_site=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM site WHERE id=?");
$connect_site->execute(array(1));
$site=$connect_site->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: session_start should go first.

Comment: The error message talks about line 13 in connection.php, but what you have shown us does not even appear to have 13 lines - unless you have trailing whitespace/newlines _after_ the `?>`. Remove that `?>`, it is not necessary at the very end of a script file - and that it frequently causes errors like this, which is why most coding guidelines recommend that anyway.

Comment: @Jonnix I tried it, still same.

Comment: If you moved it, you should have gotten at least a slightly different error message.

Comment: @04FS I tried that too, nothings change

Comment: Why are you trying to pick up the session only after making the database connection to begin with? If _that_ throws an exception and you output it in this place, ob_start afterwards will be to late anyway, in that case session_start will always fail here.

Comment: You can also try and use `headers_sent` to figure out where the headers got sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put always the

```
session_start();
```

At the start of all your codes.
Nothing had to go before whatever it is :)

Enjoy coding !

Comment: It's already at the top of all pages. All the pages are contains similar code structure like start of index.php But the other pages runs well, index.php doesn't.

Comment: But on you're code it's not in first so try it out, when i say first it's the first line of all.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in connection.php

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start();  ?>
<?php
    try {
      $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb','testuser','123456');
      $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); }
    catch(PDOExpception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you dude, the problem was the spaces before `<?php`.